# Replace links on post save/update in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url-shortener

I would like use short urls in wordpress post content (not the post permalink). So when I setup a new link in my post content, I would like if this url will be shortened with a service. I have an url shorten tool with yourls api, it works fine. My problem is, I unable change all long url in post to the new shortened url.

My function looks like this:

```
 add_action( 'save_post', 'save_book_meta', 10, 3 );
 function save_book_meta( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
 global $wpdb;

 preg_match_all('|<a.*(?=href=\"([^\"]*)\")[^>]*>([^<]*)</a>|i', $post->post_content, $match);

 $new_content = $post->post_content;

 foreach($match[1] as $link){
     $yapikey = '********';
     $api_url =  'https://yourdomain.com/yourls-api.php';
     $longUrl = $link;

     // Init the CURL session
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);            // No header in the result
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // Return, do not echo result
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);              // This is a POST request
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(     // Data to POST
             'url' => $longUrl,
             'format'   => 'json',
             'action'   => 'shorturl',
             'signature' => $yapikey
         ));

     // Fetch and return content
     $data = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);

     // Do something with the result. Here, we echo the long URL
     $data = json_decode( $data );

     if($data->shorturl) {
         str_replace($link, $data->shorturl, $new_content);
     }
 }

 // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
 remove_action('save_post', 'save_book_meta' );

 $post_new = array(
     'ID'       => $post_id,
     'post_content'  => $new_content
   );

 $post_id = wp_update_post( $post_new, true );
 add_action( 'save_post', 'save_book_meta' );

}
```

How can I replace all long url with the new shortened urls and save the updated content?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easiest to use the filter

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'save_book_meta' , '99', 2 ); 

function save_book_meta( $data , $postarr ) {
    // find your urls and do the replacements on $data['post_content'] here
    return $data;
}
```

EDIT: It looks like another viable filter option to use is https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/content_save_pre which may work even better as there has been no sanitation performed on the content yet.